# Uint8ClampedArray to Uint8Array to base64

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a similar method of converting a Uint8ClampedArray to a regular array.

```
var typedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray([1, 2, 3, 4]);
var normalArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(typedArray);
```

But then converting from Uint8ClampedArray to Uint8Array?

I understand there are differences in how values are assigned but is rather confusing to look into for me as the Uint8ClampedArray involves an image that is being drawn onto a canvas for which a downloadable blob link is made.

My data looks like this:
[image]

And then I try to convert it into base64 with this:
https://gist.github.com/enepomnyaschih/72c423f727d395eeaa09697058238727

EDIT: Already tried putting it into the constructor of Uint8Array but when converting to base64 it does not appear to be valid.

```
new Uint8Array(imageData.data)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array/Uint8Array#Syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using canvas.toDataURL instead of trying to convert this myself.